# Clean way to specialize (differentiate) the behaviour of Backbone.Model parse method

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, collections

I have a simple model called `BaseModel` that extends from a `Backbone.Model`. According to [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-parse) documentation I've overridden `parse` method to work with a preexisting API.

The `parse` method is called in two different situation. When from a collection I want to fetch to grab all data. When from a model I want to fetch a specific data.

Within `BaseModel` to differentiate the behavior I'm doing the following.

```
parse : function(response, options) {
    var result;        

    if(options.collection) {
        // I'm coming from the fetch that belongs to the collection

        // manipulate result here...
    } else {
        // I'm coming from the fetch that belongs to the model

        // manipulate result here...
    }
    return result;
}
```

Is this appraoch valid or is there a better way to achieve this?

**Edit 1**

I thought on Andrew answer but the situation I need to manage is weird. In fact, when the `parse` method is called the first time (from the collection) data are parsed and properties for the model are created. Then, when the `parse` method is called from the model itself, additional data are parsed and properties for the model are merged to the first ones.

**Edit 2**

In my situation, for example, response coming from collection contains an array of objects where each object has a property `a`. Conversion can be applied, e.g. date obj. Then, response coming from model contains `b`. Also here conversion can be applied. At the end both properties will be merged into the same model but they are coming from different `fetch` calls.

Notice that response in collection is already an array. So, I do not to differentiate or split nothing here. I would just know that if I come from collection, I will find `a`, `b` otherwise.

Read the `fetch` in the collection as **give me all models**, while the other call as **based on a model returned from the collection, enrich it by details**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backbone.Collection also has a `parse` method. In my opinion the correct way is to implement it for both your `BaseModel` and your `Collection`.

The collections parse method only needs convert the data to be an array of unparsed models. It then delegates to the `BaseModel` parse method automatically to parse each one individually.

e.g.,

```
BaseModel {
parse : function(response, options) {
    var result;               
    // I'm coming from the fetch that belongs to the model

    // manipulate result here...

    return result;
}
}

BaseCollection {
parse : function(response, options){
    // I'm coming from the fetch that belongs to the collection
    // Turn it into an array.
    return response.split('mydelim');
}
}
```

From your edit 2, It looks like your approach is the right idea. I would however say that if I where to do it, I would test the returned object for properties rather than the context of the call so I don't need to care about the datasource,

```
parse : function(response, options) {
    var result = {};        

    if(response.a){
        result.c = response.a;
    } else if(response.b){
        result.c = response.b;
    }

    ...

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. +1. I agree with you. But what do you mean with *turn it into an array*?. See also my edit.

Comment: @flexaddicted A Collection by default expects an array of objects as the return when updating from your datasource. SO you need to take whtever is returned from your datasource and convert it to an array of objects. In my example I just split it, so `andrewmydelimbob` would become `['andrew', 'bob']` which your model parse could then convert to `{name : 'andrew'}` etc..

Comment: So in the collection case, should I create the array of objects (parsed in the correct manner) doing a push for each item returned? Are u talking about this? Thanks.

Comment: @flexaddicted You don't need to parse the objects themselves. Collections will internally create a model calling the models' parse method to populate it. All you need to return is an array of values that your underlying models can then parse. If you post an example of your response string I could explain better.

Comment: If possible see Edit 2. I've explained what I want to achieve. Thanks for the support.